# Using MediaEement in WPF while respecting MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, media-player, mediaelement

I'm making a media player in WPF while trying to respecting the MVVM pattern. MediaElement is a XAML element that has a few methods such as Play(), Pause() and Stop(). How can I interact with these methods without having to put code on MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: Just put code inside MainWindow.xaml.cs. MVVM is an architectural pattern with the goal to decouple view from business logic (model). Code-behind doesn't violate this pattern and is sometimes inevitable.

Comment: Okay man thanks for clarifying, will do

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution that wasn't necessary. It's okay to put code in MainWindow.xaml.cs if necessary.

@BionicCode said:

Just put code inside MainWindow.xaml.cs. MVVM is an architectural pattern with the goal to decouple view from business logic (model). Code-behind doesn't violate this pattern and is sometimes inevitable.